# get anchor with a specific text inside li using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code

```
<ul id="selector">
  <li> <a> first </a> </li>
  <li> <a> Second </a> </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the anchor with specific text and trigger a click event on it.

```
$("#selector li").find('a').contains('first').click()
```

Error :

```
$(...).find(...).contains is not a function
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a double quote `"`.

Comment: Sorry,  missed it while posting. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the double quote `"` at beginning of li selector. you also need to use selector `:contains` instead of `.contains()` because:

> **.contains()** Check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element.

and

> **:contains** Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
 $("#selector li").find('a:contains(first)').click()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I replaced contains with `:contains` as you said.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul id="selector">
  <li> <a> first </a> </li>
  <li> <a> Second </a> </li>
</ul>  

$("#selector li").find('a:contains(first)').click(function(){
alert('');
});
```

> [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ggtabjuj/)